Buckets Not Appearing in Dataplex Catalog Search
I’m trying to make my Cloud Storage buckets visible in the NEW Dataplex catalog search (not in Data Catalog). I’ve created multiple buckets, but they don’t appear in the dataplex catalog search results.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Verified that the buckets exist and are accessible via Cloud Storage.
Added permissions for Dataplex to list the buckets in Cloud Storage directly.
Despite these steps, the buckets are still not visible in Dataplex.

Questions:

Are there additional configurations or permissions required to make
the buckets discoverable in the Dataplex catalog?
Is there a specific setup process to ensure Dataplex recognizes and
includes these resources in its catalog?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

I replicated your scenario and I was able to get the result you are looking for. I did follow these steps and I also uploaded a test sample in my bucket.

You can check again the IAM permissions, verify if you have the dataplex Owner, Admin and Editor

Try to also add the Storage Admin and Storage Object Viewer in the IAM permission

Then after following the steps above kindly wait for about 30 minutes for the configuration to take effect



Hello thanks for your reply. Should i add the roles to the dataplex service account or add them to my account ?

I add it to my account, so that all projects using Dataplex will have the permissions you need, since you are the only one using it.
